# Uploading a dataframe to BigQuery results in null values

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api

I have the following dataframe that I'm uploading to BigQuery. When uploaded, all columns except for sessions and date end up with null values in Bigquery despite having 0 null values in the dataframe.

Why would this be? I've changed to the correct datatypes and specified the schema to Bigquery to no avail.

[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that WITHOUT the api giving appropriate feedback any spaces in the column names result in the values all being uploaded as null to the database.

EDIT: this also occurs if using a ":" in the column name that can be found when pulling custom events from google analytics

Comment: I experienced the same with a `-` in the title. I wish there was any kind of error message or warning